# Queria separa uns dados em php

Tags: php

```html
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['acao'])){?>
       <?php  $acao = $_GET['acao'];
       switch ($acao) {
        case 'buscar':
          
           $dados = array( 
     array(
           "video"  => 'LWzwjcgh7_A',
           "imagem" => 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LWzwjcgh7_A/mqdefault.jpg',
           "titulo" => 'Amado Batista Princesa',
           "subtitulo" => 'Dados do video',
           ),
      ); 
         break;
        default:
         # code...
         break;
       }
    echo(json_encode($dados));
 }
 ?>
```

Queria separar essa parte vou fazer um loop aqui vou duplicar

```
 array(
                            "video"  => 'LWzwjcgh7_A',
                            "imagem" => 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LWzwjcgh7_A/mqdefault.jpg',
                            "titulo" => 'Amado Batista Princesa',
                            "subtitulo" => 'Dados do video',
                         ),
```

Comment: Na verdade isso e json mais nao estou vendo as array quando coloco echo

Comment: Poderia melhorar a redação da pergunta? Eu achei vago e confuso.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um erro logo no começo do código:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['acao'])){?>
```

Esse sinal no final **?>** fecha a TAG PHP, ou seja, o que vier a seguir vai virar apenas texto HTML.

Para separar a ARRAY seguindo a lógica do seu código:

`echo $dados['video'];` //resulta LWzwjcgh7_A

`echo $dados['imagem'];` //https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LWzwjcgh7_A/mqdefault.jpg

`echo $dados['titulo'];` //Amado Batista Princesa

`echo $dados['subtitulo'];` //Dados do video